# Easy way to compare values within all dicts in list of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Let's say I have a list of dicts, called mydict, that looks like like this:

```
[{'id': 6384,
  'character': 'Thomas A. Anderson / Neo',
  'credit_id': '52fe425bc3a36847f80181c1',
  'movie_id': 603},
 {'id': 2975,
  'character': 'Morpheus',
  'credit_id': '52fe425bc3a36847f801818d',
  'movie_id': 603},
 {'id': 530,
  'character': 'Trinity',
  'credit_id': '52fe425bc3a36847f8018191',
  'movie_id': 603},
 {'id': 1331,
  'character': 'Agent Smith',
  'credit_id': '52fe425bc3a36847f8018195',
  'movie_id': 603},
 {'id': 3165802,
  'character': 'MP Sergeant #1',
  'credit_id': '62ade87f4142910051c8e002',
  'movie_id': 28},
 {'id': 18471,
  'character': 'Self',
  'credit_id': '6259ed263acd2016291eef43',
  'movie_id': 963164},
 {'id': 74611,
  'character': 'Self',
  'credit_id': '6259ed37ecaef515ff68cae6',
  'movie_id': 963164}]
```

and I want to get all pairs of mydict['id'] values that have the same mydict['movie_id'] value - using only Python standard libraries. Essentially, returning

```
(6384, 2975)
(6384, 530)
(6384, 1331)
....
(18471, 74611)
```

Looping through every possible combination seems possible, but slow, with something like this.

```
results=[]
for i in mydict:
    for j in mydict:
        current = i['movie_id'] 
        next = j['movie_id']
    if current==next:
        results.append(i['id'], j['id'])
```

Is there a dictionary comprehension way to achieve the same result?

Comment: You could use a `map` function I guess.

Comment: @ARK1375 how would that work?

Comment: It seems to me that there are fundamentally two questions here: how to find dictionaries that have the same `movie_id` value (i.e., how to *group* them by `movie_id`), and then how to create pairs within each group. Both are common duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a [collections.defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to group by `movie_id`.  Then use [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to loop over them pairwise:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

d = defaultdict(list)
for movie in credits:
    d[movie['movie_id']].append(movie['id'])

for group in d.values():
    for pair in combinations(group, 2):
        print(pair)
```

For the given dataset, this outputs:

```
(6384, 2975)
(6384, 530)
(6384, 1331)
(2975, 530)
(2975, 1331)
(530, 1331)
(18471, 74611)
```

Comment: @Mark Thanks for noticing. It is fixed now.

Comment: really nice approach.

Comment: Thanks - i think the itertools combinations was exactly what I was looking for. Very readable, too.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and understandable solution is to use the pandas library to do so.

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = mydict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_data)
print(
    df[ df['id'] == df['movie_id'] ]
    )
```

This should work ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `groupby` and `combinations`,

While using the `groupby` it's expected the similar `movie_id` appear together in main list, If not you have to sort the main list with `movie_id`.

```
In [18]: from itertools import groupby

In [19]: from itertools import combinations

In [20]: for k,l in groupby(mydict, key=lambda x:x['movie_id']):
    ...:     print(list(combinations([i.get('id') for i in l], 2)))
    ...: 
[(6384, 2975), (6384, 530), (6384, 1331), (2975, 530), (2975, 1331), (530, 1331)]
[]
[(18471, 74611)]
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this requires the list items to appear together in the original list, which may require a sort.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`:

```
#lst is your list of dicts
out = pd.DataFrame(lst).groupby('movie_id')['id'].apply(
    lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x, 2))).to_dict()
```

Using `itertools`:

```
out = {
        k: list(combinations([d['id'] for d in list(g)], 2))
        for k, g in groupby(lst, lambda x: x['movie_id'])
      }
```

print(out):

```
{28: [],
 603: [(6384, 2975),
  (6384, 530),
  (6384, 1331),
  (2975, 530),
  (2975, 1331),
  (530, 1331)],
 963164: [(18471, 74611)]}
```